# How to prevent Angular Material mat-select change option?

Tags: angular, angular-material

```html
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
  <mat-label>Favorite food</mat-label>
  <mat-select [formControl]="topFormControl" [(value)]="topSelectValue">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let food of foods" [value]="food" >
      {{food.viewValue}}
    </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

```js
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.topFormControl.valueChanges
      .pipe(
        startWith(this.topFormControl.value),
        pairwise()
      ).subscribe(
        ([old, cur]) => {
          if(
            //cur.value === 's'
          ){
            //prevent user select the option, force mat-select still shows the old option.
          }
        }
      );
  }

  foods: Food[] = [
    { value: 's', viewValue: 'Steak' },
    { value: 'p', viewValue: 'Pizza' },
    { value: 't', viewValue: 'Tacos' },
  ];
```

Is there any solution when user select Steak in Favorite food, prevent mat-select to show Steak but keep the old option?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [setValue](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl#setValue) method on FormControl and pass `emitEvent:false` as second argument to stop triggering valueChanges again.

```
 ngOnInit(): void {
        this.topFormControl.valueChanges
          .pipe(
            startWith(this.topFormControl.value),
            pairwise()
          ).subscribe(
            ([old, cur]) => {
              if(
                //cur.value === 's'
              ){
                this.topFormControl.setValue(curr.value,{emitEvent:false})
              }
            }
          );
      }
```

Comment: Many thanks Chellappan, it works! But I don't understand why when I use `cur` rather than `cur.value`, it won't work. But console.log(cur), cur isn't a object. Why it has property value? why it won't work if use cur rather than cur.value? Could you please help teach me? Thanks

Comment: Beacuse in your html you are assigning whole object to value property